# SSIS potential loss of data when converting

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

Working with SQL server 2014 ans SSIS, I am having the following issue in a data flow:

> Data Source: There was an error  "The value could not be converted
>   because of a potential loss of data.".

This is the query:

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(M.ActiveLEDZones, '') [ActiveLEDZones__c]
    , M.Weight [Weight__c]
    , M.WeightStand [WeightStand__c]
    , M.wifi [WIFI__c]
FROM [dbo].[ModelComparison] M 
WHERE CAST(M.CreateDate AS DATE) >= '2012-01-01'
```

using a distinct I get these values:

```
ActiveLEDZones__c
3
126
28
36
12
9
384
72
tbd
128
8
2
14
6
NA
16

1
10
0
N/A
32
18
5
64
4
```

Tables information:

```
Source: varchar(5)
Target: nvarchar(5)
```

I am using a data conversion in SSIS:

[image]

Comment: To be clear, you're converting `ActiveLEDZones__c` from `varchar(5)` to `nvarchar(5)`?

Comment: Which component in the Data Flow is producing the error?  Source, Conversion, or Destination?

Comment: yeas I am converting ActiveLEDZones__c from varchar(5) to nvarchar(5) and the component that is giving me the error is the Source task

Comment: What happens if you take the Data Conversion component out?   I think varchar would convert to nvarchar implicitly.   Also what is the datatype of the `CreateDate` column in the source table?

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider 2 points:

**1st**

When using `ISNULL(M.ActiveLEDZones, '') [ActiveLEDZones__c]` in your query, this function will not take the original column data length `varchar(5)`, it will take the longest length found in this query which can cause a similar issue, try using a `CAST` function to precise the column data length.

```
CAST(ISNULL(M.ActiveLEDZones, '') AS VARCHAR(5)) [ActiveLEDZones__c]
```

*Additional Testing*

use the following queries to create table and check the created table structure:

```
SELECT
ISNULL(M.ActiveLEDZones, '') [ActiveLEDZones__c]
, M.Weight [Weight__c]
, M.WeightStand [WeightStand__c]
, M.wifi [WIFI__c]
INTO tblTemp_1
FROM [dbo].[ModelComparison] M 
WHERE CAST(M.CreateDate AS DATE) >= '2012-01-01'
```

AND the following

```
SELECT
CAST(ISNULL(M.ActiveLEDZones, '') AS VARCHAR(5)) [ActiveLEDZones__c]
, M.Weight [Weight__c]
, M.WeightStand [WeightStand__c]
, M.wifi [WIFI__c]
INTO tblTemp_2
FROM [dbo].[ModelComparison] M 
WHERE CAST(M.CreateDate AS DATE) >= '2012-01-01'
```

you will see that tblTemp_1 `[ActiveLEDZones__c]` column differs from tblTemp_1 
 `[ActiveLEDZones__c]`

**2nd**

You can use `CAST(ISNULL(M.ActiveLEDZones, '') AS NVARCHAR(5))` instead of `ISNULL(M.ActiveLEDZones, '')` so the source column will be readed as `Nvarchar(5)` and there is no need to use `Data Conversion Componenent`

the query will be

```
SELECT
CAST(ISNULL(M.ActiveLEDZones, '') AS NVARCHAR(5)) [ActiveLEDZones__c]
, M.Weight [Weight__c]
, M.WeightStand [WeightStand__c]
, M.wifi [WIFI__c]
FROM [dbo].[ModelComparison] M 
WHERE CAST(M.CreateDate AS DATE) >= '2012-01-01'
```